# Generate query string with ramda

Tags: javascript, json, ramda.js

I have an object which represent an array of filter's. any object in array has `id` and `value`. now i want to generate query-string from this array :

```
{ filtered: '[{"id":"tags","value":["soap"]}]',
  limit: '10',
  offset: '0',
  sorted: '[]' }
```

the output hsould be look like below :

```
/item?filtered=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22tags%22%2C%22value%22%3A%5B%22soap%22%5D%7D%5D&limit=10&offset=0&sorted=%5B%5D
```

now how to generate nested query like this with ramda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd just use an existing library for this (there are many, search npm for `query string`). If you were to do it yourself using particularly ramda though:

```
const qs = R.compose(
  s => `?${s}`, // Prepend a ?
  R.join('&'), // Join each segment of the query with '&'
  R.map(R.join('=')), // Join the key-value pairs with '='
  R.map(R.map(encodeURIComponent)), // encode keys and values
  R.toPairs, // convert the object to pairs like `['limit', 5]`
)(input)
```